# Is ASP.NET Core MVC compatible with ASP.net MVC5?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I have an existing library which contains precompiled MVC5 views and other stuff like Base MVC controller etc. Can I use same library with ASP.NET Core MVC application?
Will it be supported completely?

Comment: No, it's not. While the controllers and API looks similarly from a high level, below that it's completely different. ASP.NET Core is a complete rewrite and it removed completely dependency on `System.Web.*` namespace, which the old ASP.NET heavily depends on and which prevented it from being truly platform independent, because `System.Web.*` is heavily tied to IIS webserver

Answer (score 0):

By the description looks like the answer in your case is going to be No.

The way to understand it would be:

> can the assembly target .Net core, if yes, then it can target aspnet
>   core as well.

If no, then you may be able to run your it as part of aspnet core on full framework, but I doubt that will also not work in your case.